# How to implement `Default` for a raw pointer?

Tags: types, rust

When using raw points in a struct, Rust doesn't allow to derive from Default.

eg:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Foo {
    bar: *mut Foo,
    baz: usize,
}
```

Reports

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `*mut Foo: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
impl Default for *mut Foo {
    fn default() -> *mut Foo {
        ptr::null_mut()
    }
}
```

This gives an error:

```
impl doesn't use types inside crate
```

Is there a way to declare `Default` for the raw pointer?

Otherwise I'll have to write explicit `default` functions for any `struct` which contains a raw pointer, OK in this example, but for larger structs it can be tedious, so I'd like to be able to avoid it in some cases.

Comment: Now I'm wondering, if someone actively decided that raw pointers shouldn't impl `Default` or if the impl was just forgotten...

Comment: I have create an issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to declare Default for the raw pointer?

**No**, currently there isn't. Either the trait or the type needs to be defined in the crate, in which the trait-impl is written (so called "orphan rules").

However, you don't need to manually implement `Default` for all of your types containing a pointer. You can create a new type, which wraps a raw pointer and does implement `Default`. Then you can just use this new type in all of your structs and simply derive `Default`.

```
struct ZeroedMutPtr<T>(pub *mut T);

impl<T> Default for ZeroedMutPtr<T> { ... }
```